# The proper way to include additional CSS for IE background support?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple style for my CSS that stretched my background beautifully in Firefox and Chrome, but with this code, IE centers the background and doesn't stretch accordingly.

```
html{
     background: url(images/bg4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
   }
```

I take it IE doesn't recognize tags 2 through 5, but is there a way to accomplish this same sort of effect with additional code or am I stuck with IE just centering the image and not stretching it?

Thanks

(Also, I would have posted on my normal account but openID is giving me fits right now)

Comment: You can request an account merge later by emailing team@stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a rule that targets IE only

```
html{
     background: url(images/bg4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
background:url(images/bg4.jpg) no-repaeat center center\9; // this rule will affect all IE verisons but other browsers
   }
```

You might want to make a custom image for IE, if you can't archieve what you want with the same image. For exmaple, make bg5.jpg with already sstretched background.